# How to get user IP address in API model in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ip-address, asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

I am not having issue getting user IP address while the code is running in web API controller but in model I am actually unable to use:

```
this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
```

The reason I need need user IP because I need to geolocate its country by comparing it via data available from a third party provider. I could do this during web API controller phase but it is better to have in model, this way I can create a custom annotation to do my job as I will need to reuse the code in several models.

Comment: get the context from `IHttpContextAccesor` injected into the desired service class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're breaking SOLID here. It's not appropriate for you model to know about `HttpContext` or how to retrieve a remote IP address from that. The logic you want to encapsulate in your model simply needs an IP address, so *that* is what you should give it. This can either be provided in the constructor of your model class or just as a param to the particular method(s) that need to utilize it. For example, create a method like:

```
public void GeolocateByIP(string ip)
{
    // do geolocation
}
```

In your controller action, then, you simply do something like:

```
model.GeolocateByIP(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString());
```

Comment: This actually makes sense, I was wondering why I was getting null IHttpContextAccessor in the constructor of my model.

Comment: The `HttpContextAccessor` service is not registered by default, as there's a slight performance hit, and ASP.NET Core is religious about only including what is absolutely necessary in your pipeline. It can be added, if you need it, via `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`. However, here you should still just pass the IP address string instead.

Comment: But I already added it as singleton, I have this line of code in my startup.cs
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Comment: First, you should *not* have that line at all. Second, that has nothing to do with `HttpContext`.

Comment: I added services.AddHttpContextAccessor() but debugger still shows it is null in constructor when I call it

Comment: 1) Your model class must be instantiated by the service collection, or the dependency will not be satisfied. In other words, if you do something like `new MyModel()` or your model instance is coming as an action param, for instance, that will not work. 2) The `HttpContext` is only available during the context of a request. If you're using this class outside of a controller action, for example, there's a high likelihood it would be null regardless.

Comment: Yes I was using it in the model class itself (outside the controller), this is why I see it is Null.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `HttpContext` by injecting `IHttpContextAccesor` in asp.net core.

```
public class ModelClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ModelClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```